# Update tabela de registros duplicados com condições

Tags: mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados, sql-update

ola amigos eu tenho uma tabela e gostaria de fazer uma atualização nos registros, de forma a pegar os NOMES que se repetem e colocar como ATIVO = 0 apena os quais DATA_CADASTRO são antigos!
tabela:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                  pessoas                         |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
| id | nome   | time |    data_cadastro    | ativo |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
| 1  | luiz   |  A   | 2019-10-05 10:52:01 | 1     |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
| 2  | carlos |  B   | 2019-10-20 20:52:01 | 1     |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
| 3  | maria  |  C   | 2019-09-15 10:50:30 | 1     |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
| 4  | maria  |  C   | 2019-09-16 10:40:50 | 1     |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
| 5  | carlos |  B   | 2019-10-20 20:55:01 | 1     |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
```

o resultado que gostaria que aparecesse

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                  pessoas                         |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
| id | nome   | time |    data_cadastro    | ativo |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
| 1  | luiz   |  A   | 2019-10-05 10:52:01 | 1     |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
| 2  | carlos |  B   | 2019-10-20 20:52:01 | 0     |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
| 3  | maria  |  C   | 2019-09-15 10:50:30 | 0     |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
| 4  | maria  |  C   | 2019-09-16 10:40:50 | 1     |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
| 5  | carlos |  B   | 2019-10-20 20:55:01 | 1     |
+----+--------+------+---------------------+-------+
```

estou tentando assim:
 **"UPDATE pessoas SET ativo=0 WHERE nome= 'maria'"**
porem esta mudando todos registro nome='maria' sem pegar a data_cadastro mais velha
aceito toda ajuda e melhorias...

Comment: Pesquise por EXISTS

Comment: isso é bem vago @Motta, explique melhor como exists vai resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso precisa de uma sub-query ou um join para resolver, porque os registros a serem alterados são aqueles que aparecem mais de uma vez, e com a data diferente da máxima.

Esses registros poderiam ser retornados com algo assim:

```
SELECT nome, max(data_cadastro) data_cadastro
          FROM pessoas 
         GROUP BY nome;
```

Ou seja, traz os registros que são os mais atuais (`max(data_cadastro)`). Teria de fazer uma query onde fizesse os updates de todos menos esses, mas seria mais simples deixar todos como ativo = 0 e depois só esses para ativo = 1.

Para isso, basta fazer um join dessa sub-query no update, assim:

```
UPDATE pessoas SET ativo = 0;

UPDATE pessoas p 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT nome, max(data_cadastro) data_cadastro
          FROM pessoas 
         GROUP BY nome
      ) p2
    ON p2.nome = p.nome
   AND p2.data_cadastro = p.data_cadastro
    SET p.ativo = 1;
```

Veja aqui o exemplo funcionando: [http://sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/417e19c/2)

Comment: testei aqui e sua resposta esclareceu bem oque eu precisava Ricardo Pontual, muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento.. pude pesquisar sobre MIN e MAX no qual ira me ajudar em outras duvidas...

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver isso, você precisa primeiro identificar os registros com nome repetido que estão ativos. De acordo com a estrutura da tabela que você informou, a seguinte query pode selecionar os repetidos.

```
select nome from pessoas where ativo = 1 group by nome having count(*) > 1
```

Pegando apenas o exemplo da Maria, para pegar o ativo mais antigo você poderia fazer assim

```
select id from pessoas where nome = 'Maria' and ativo = 1 order by data_cadastro LIMIT 1
```

O update dela ficaria assim

```
update pessoas set ativo = 0 WHERE id in (select id from pessoas where nome = 'Maria' order by data_cadastro LIMIT 1)
```

Seria mais prático alterar todos os nomes repetidos de uma vez. Você pode inativar os que tiverem o ID mais antigo. A seguinte query pega todos os IDs mais antigos dos nomes repetidos.

```
select min(id) from pessoas where nome in (
select nome from pessoas where ativo = 1 group by nome having count(*) > 1
) GROUP BY nome
```

Com base nesse resultado, você pode fazer o seu update

```
update pessoas set ativo = 0 WHERE id in (
select min(id) from pessoas where nome in (
select nome from pessoas where ativo = 1 group by nome having count(*) > 1
) GROUP BY nome)
```

Comment: essa sua solução Bins vai me ajudar em outra tabela que tenho, de inicio eu precisava da filtragem pela data menor, igual o amigo @Ricardo Pontual deu uma solução que atendeu o esclarecimento que precisava... muito obrigado pela sua atenção e ajuda!!